# Spring Data JPA findAllBy ... in ... orderBy input list

Tags: java, mysql, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using JPA with Spring Boot in Kotlin/Java. I'm trying to find the proper and efficient way to do findBy ... In OrderBy input.

I got a list of the Ids I want to find  and I want an ordered output with the same order. This is what JPA allows you:

```
@Repository
interface PhotoRepository : JpaRepository<Photo, String>{
    // Which is the same as this query
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Photo p where p.id in :var1")
    fun findAllByIdIn(var1: List<String>, pageable: Pageable): List<Photo>
}
```

Would be great if JPA allows you to do something like this:

```
@Repository
interface PhotoRepository : JpaRepository<Photo, String>{
    @Query("SELECT p FROM Photo p where p.id in :var1 order by :var1")
    fun findAllByIdInOrderByvar1(var1: List<String>, pageable: Pageable): List<Photo>
}
```

The size of the id list is between 500- 1500 items. There are lots of records in the database and the idea of select all the records is not feasible

The contemplated solution is to do a `findAllByIdIn` and then match the records with the ids in list, which I think is not the proper solution, there are extra operations. The idea of changing the database is also contemplated.

Comment: I don't understand the second example where you say "order by :var1" considering var1 is a list.

Comment: Yes, the idea is that the query will be like: "SELECT p FROM Photo p where p.id in (1,2,3) order by FIELD(1,2,3)" from MySQL 8

Comment: so "nativeQuery=true" in the Query annotation to use such a query is not an option?

Comment: "JPA" doesn't do methods called "findXXX"; that is Spring Data JPA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get all the items in a certain id, with `findAllByIdIn`, to get the correct order, I used the following method:

```
private fun getOrderedItemsFromOneListToAnother(photosOrder: List<String>, 
                                                photosFound: List<Photo>): List<Photo>{
    val mapStringIdsOrder = photosOrder.mapIndexed { index, s ->  s to index}.toMap()

    Collections.sort(photosFound, Comparator { o1: Photo, o2: Photo->
        Integer.compare(mapStringIdsOrder.getOrDefault(o1.id,photosOrder.size), 
        mapStringIdsOrder.getOrDefault(o2.id, photosOrder.size))})

    return photosOrder
}
```